# Image fallback when there is no internet connection to load Google Map Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've got an application (WebApp) that is running local (of course). However, I can suggest users might have the app downloaded, but not always have 3G/WiFi when running the app. Therefor, the Google Map would not load when a user doesn't has an internet connection, since it needs the web API.

As a fallback, I would like to show an image ('screenshot') when the map could not be loaded.

What would be the most appropriate solution? Thanks!

The whole map canvas works with help of these code pieces

**HTML**

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map-canvas { 
width:100%;
height:200px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.81199,4.66656);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
// END OF GOOGLE MAPS //
```

**External Google API script**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **wouldn't** use the following line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

On `window.onload` you would check to see if `google.maps` exists and then use an `if/else` statement to toggle between the conditions - `initialize`, or load the image in the map's place. Something like:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var foundGoogle, img;
  foundGoogle = typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object';
  if (foundGoogle) {
    initialize();
  } else {
    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'screenshot.png';
    document.getElementById('map-canvas').appendChild(img);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, that seems like a great solution! Will check asap and feedback. Thanks!

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer, I've just corrected the way the image is added to the DOM because it was incorrect.

Comment: shouldn't it be `new Image();`